# Uppercase vs lower case: Name is Lambdadelta. What is this in symbols? λδ? ΛΔ? Λδ? λΔ?

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-translation

[Lambdadelta](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Lambdadelta) is a character from the 2 Japanese anime/manga/VN series Higurashi No Naku Koro Ni (When The Cicadas Cry) and Umineko No Naku Koro Ni (When The Seagulls Cry).

There's this Umineko arc [Memoirs of the ΛΔ](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Memoirs_of_the_%CE%9B%CE%94). So in symbols 'Lambdadelta' is really ΛΔ instead of λδ, Λδ and λΔ? Well I guess the other option would be Λδ but probably not λδ or λΔ since I guess the lambda has to be capital.

**Edit**: Actually there's a spoilerous reason why the name 'Lambdadelta' is associated with the numbers 3 (or 30), 4 and 34. I read somewhere that if this is the case then we should keep both symbols capital. Any source possibly to confirm (or disprove) this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Why would it be uppercase or lowercase? That's not really a language thing, but solely down to style and aesthetic preference. Similarly, the network ABC's logo is all lowercase, but NBC's is all uppercase.

Comment: @cmw well it's not a logo or a company or item like iPhone, AoT (shortcut for Attack on Titan), etc. It's the name of a person...?

Comment: If it's their name, then you would spell it out like any other name: Lambdadelta. It's a fictional name, though. Go with the author's representation.

Comment: In the light of the comments and votes, I'll have to close this question as unclear. It can be reopened once you edit to clarify what it is that someone familiar with Greek or Latin but not the fictional character could give you.

Comment: @Asteroides oh lol thanks it's supposed to be 'but probably not' instead of just 'but probably'

Comment: "The Witch of Certainty, who has lived for a thousand years." ← cute, but, I'm afraid, not old enough for Ancient Greek by a lot ;-)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel LOL NICE

Comment: To stir up the apophenia, the transpose, Δλ, Delta-lambda,  is a finite increment to the quantity λ, the number 30 in Greek.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Interesting. Thanks. Maybe that's some symbolism in the series. I believe the point of the name is to be like '34' or '3, then 4' and then a lot of other characters associated with ΛΔ are related to the numbers 3 and 4. Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [traditional Greek number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals), ΛΔ' indicates the number 34. These numerals are traditionally written in uppercase in modern usage; they're not especially common, but are still used for aesthetic in some cases, somewhat like Roman numerals are in English.

Comment: Thanks Draconis♦! I found the same answer on reddit. I posted it just now.

Answer (score 0):

[Same answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18277) as Draconis♦ found in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/umineko/comments/uxvrfl/comment/ia487da/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> Ancient and Modern greek numerals use capital letters, if you want to
> keep the 34 connection you have to use them capitalized.
>
> (Or just use the lowercase letters and claim that R07 used the
> Byzantine numerals, but I'd consider that less probable)
>
> (...) You treat them as 30 and 4.
>
> The source I used is in french, [but here it is](https://www.academia.edu/11614075/Syst%C3%A8mes_num%C3%A9raux_en_Gr%C3%A8ce_ancienne_description_et_mise_en_perspective_historique_CultureMATH_website_2007_revised_version_).